# How to simplify this Laravel PHP code to one Eloquent query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I assume that this should all be in one query in order to prevent duplicate data in the database. Is this correct?

How do I simplify this code into one Eloquent query?

```
$user = User::where( 'id', '=', $otherID )->first();

if( $user != null )
{
    if( $user->requestReceived() )
        accept_friend( $otherID );
    else if( !$user->requestSent() )
    {
        $friend = new Friend;
        $friend->user_1= $myID;
        $friend->user_2 = $otherID;
        $friend->accepted = 0;
        $friend->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$user->requestReceived()` doing?

Comment: What is the SQL generated?

Comment: What are you meant by "prevent duplicate data in the database"

Comment: @RickJames first it does `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = some_number`, then he checks whether he gets any results, then it's a simple `UPDATE tablename WHERE...` else `INSERT INTO tablename...` - basically he's doing uniqueness check in PHP. In his case, uniqueness check is "are there any records" and that's why I think (probably much like you are) that what has to be done to prevent duplication is to place unique constraint on appropriate columns. Since the question lacks info on table structure(s), it's guesswork to suggest which columns need to be unique.

Comment: Do you have a `UNIQUE` index on the column(s) that determine 'duplicate'?

Comment: @RickJames: No, I haven't used a unique index

Comment: Well, that is part of the problem, as some of the answers emphatically point out.

Comment: maybe out of topic but use  $user = User::find($otherID); instead of
$user = User::where( 'id', '=', $otherID )->first();

Answer (score 10):

> I assume that this should all be in one query in order to prevent
>   duplicate data in the database. Is this correct?

It's not correct. You prevent duplication by placing `unique` constraints on database level.

There's literally **nothing** you can do in php or any other language for that matter, that will prevent duplicates, **if** you don't have unique keys on your table(s). That's a simple fact, and if anyone tells you anything different - that person is blatantly wrong. I can explain why, but the explanation would be a lengthy one so I'll skip it.

Your code should be quite simple - just insert the data. Since it's not *exactly* clear how uniqueness is handled (it appears to be `user_2, accepted`, but there's an edge case), without a bit more data form you - it's not possible to suggest a complete solution.

You can always disregard what I wrote and try to go with suggested solutions, but they will fail miserably and you'll end up with duplicates.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. It could be either user 1 or user 2 who requested friendship. How do I add a unique key for both ways?

Comment: @Z0q for unique constraints, you can set a migration to use: `$table->unique(['user_1', 'user_2'], 'user_friend_unique');` in your `friends` table. The only thing you need to ensure is to check probably any where in your app is these pairs are already together... If I would do this, then I would do that in my model.

Answer (score 8):

I would say if there is a relationship between `User` and `Friend` you can simply employ *Laravel's* model relationship, such as:

```
$status = User::find($id)->friends()->updateOrCreate(['user_id' => $id], $attributes_to_update));
```

Thats what I would do to ensure that the new data is updated or a new one is created.

> PS: I have used updateOrCreate() on Laravel 5.2.* only. And also it would be nice to actually do some check on user existence before updating else some errors might be thrown for null.

***UPDATE***

> I'm not sure what to do. Could you explain a bit more what I should do? What about $attributes_to_update ?

Okay. Depending on what fields in the friends table marks the two friends, now using your example `user_1` and `user_2`. By the example I gave, the `$attributes_to_update` would be (assuming `otherID` is the new friend's id):

```
$attributes_to_update = ['user_2' => otherID, 'accepted' => 0 ];
```

If your relationship between `User` and `Friend` is set properly, then the `user_1` would already included in the insertion.

Furthermore,on this updateOrCreate function:

```
updateOrCreate($attributes_to_check, $attributes_to_update);
```

`$attributes_to_check` would mean those fields you want to check if they already exists before you create/update new one so if I want to ensure, the check is made when `accepted` is `0` then I can pass both say `['user_1' => 1, 'accepted' => 0]

Hope this is clearer now.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. Could you explain a bit more what I should do? What about `$attributes_to_update` ?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming "friends" here represents a many-to-many relation between users. Apparently friend requests from one user (`myID`) to another (`otherId`).

You can represent that with Eloquent as:

```
class User extends Model
{
    //...

    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends', 'myId', 'otherId')->withPivot('accepted');
    }
}
```

That is, no need for `Friend` model.

Then, I think this is equivalent to what you want to accomplish (if not, please update with clarification):

```
$me = User::find($myId);

$me->friends()->syncWithoutDetaching([$otherId => ['accepted' => 0]]);
```

(`accepted` 0 or 1, according to your business logic).

This `sync` method prevents duplicate inserts, and updates or creates any row for the given pair of "myId - otherId". You can set any number of additional fields in the pivot table with this method.

However, I agree with [@Mjh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41959246/3208258) about setting unique constraints at database level as well.

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of issue,  First of all, you have to enjoy the code and database if you are working in laravel.  For this first you create realtionship between both table `friend` and `user` in database as well as in Models . Also you have to use `unique` in database .

```
$data= array('accepted' => 0);
User::find($otherID)->friends()->updateOrCreate(['user_id', $otherID], $data));
```

This is query you can work with this . Also you can pass multiple condition here. Thanks

Comment: Does that generate `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`?

Comment: @RickJames No. It's doing `select * ... where user_id = ?`. If no row is returned - insert new row. Otherwise update the row. And no transaction is used.

Comment: False -- A separate thread could slip in between the `SELECT` and `INSERT` and do its own `INSERT`, thereby messing things up.  `SELECT, if, ...` needs a transaction.

Comment: @RickJames Misread my comment? I didn't write "no transaction is needed".

Comment: The `SELECT` may as well to be inside the transaction and `FOR UPDATE`.  Otherwise, the `SELECT` would need to be repeated when you decide to insert/update.  I stand by my statement.

Comment: I give it up, Rick :-)

Comment: I agree with you @PaulSpiegel . If no row is returned by query - insert the new row. Otherwise, update the row.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `firstOrCreate`/ `firstOrNew` methods (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)

Example (from docs) :

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);

// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrNew(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Comment: its important to know that `firstOrCreate` will persist the info to the database and return the instance were `firstOrNew` will just return the instance without persisting

Comment: that's why I let the comments :)

Answer (score -3):

use `firstOrCreate' it will do same as you did manually.

Definition of FirstOrCreate copied from the Laravel Manual.

The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the given attributes.

So according to that you should try :

```
$user = User::where( 'id', '=', $otherID )->first();
$friend=Friend::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $myId], ['user_2' => $otherId]);
```

It will check with both IDs if not exists then create record in friends table.

Comment: It is not exactly the same as I did

Comment: Your solution **doesn't prevent duplicates**.

Comment: `firstOrCreate` will cover based on the array given

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding what I'm trying to say - **it won't**. You can't use PHP or any other language to guarantee uniqueness. This is not the way to deal with database integrity.